# Jquery POST AJAX return requested page into browser

Tags: jquery, django

I use a jQuery script for post a form.
Afert AJAX request, I don't want to use the response.

My trouble is, the AJAX response is launch by browser.

My Script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button[num]').click(function(){
    $.fn.validRef($(this).attr('num'));
  });

  $.fn.validRef = function(refId){

    var R = {}  
    var form = $('#R'+refId+'Form')
    var tab = $('#R'+refId+'Tab')

    $('form input').each(function(index) {
      R[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    $('form select').each(function(index) {
      R[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/events/",
      data: R,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      error: function() { alert('err'); },
      success: function(data){
        form.hide();
        tab.hide();
      }
    });
  }

});
```

I tried to use `return false` and `console.log(data)`,
But in all case the trouble appears.

You can also give different ways to use or place the 2 previous commands.

A last thing, I use Django and the web page which request `/ajax` is not itself.

When I launch it from console it works ! But not when I use `onclick`with my function.
I declare my function like that : `function validRef(){ ... }`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the AJAX request and everything to do with the code that is **making** the AJAX request, so let's see that.

Comment: When I launch it from console it works ! But not with `onclick`.

Comment: Post the **entire** code for the function, as well as where you bind it to any events that fire it.

Comment: i m a c# dev. I think you are not return any value from function which you write in the server side. In c#, we are specifying the action name and we return some value like Response.Write(-- data to client--). Please check your server side

Comment: It's resolved, but there's no script in server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :

I add `return false` in click handle.

```
  ...
  $('button[num]').click(function(){
    $.fn.validRef($(this).attr('num'));
    return false
  });
  ...
```